# Regex to validate dropdown entries

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, dropdownbox

I have a dropdown in which I am having

```
"-- Select--"
```

as the first item. I want to check if user has choosen something else from the dropdown instead of Select.
So is there a way around to match if 
!-- Select --.
I have done this till now.

```
  "regex": /^[!-- Select --]$/,
```

Where "!" means when not Select.
I am achieving this client side.

Comment: I am looking for the regex as I am applying jquery validation in Jtable.

Comment: What `!` represents here ? It exists in your pattern but not in the text ? Is it the case ?

Comment: No, I was trying like that, but that doen't work.

Comment: Have you noticed the missing `!` from your text ? It exists in your pattern only. Please check it.

Comment: yes, it exist in pattern as I was trying the same to check if not exist, can you please update me with the regex?

Comment: Have you tried giving that item a `value=""` attribute? That way you can match against an empty string, wouldn't that be easier? :)

Comment: Btw, are you doing this server side or client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
/^(!?--\s*[Ss]elect\s*--)$/
```

You should also find [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.selectedindex.aspx) property to evaluate this item.

Comment: Let me try and then I will revert back.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you're using a big character class; instead of trying to match the opposite, try to match what you don't want and then logically reverse that.

```
/^[-]{2} Select [-]{2}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery

```
if($("#id of your select box").attr("selectedIndex") == 0) 
{
     alert("You haven't selected anything!");
}
```

You  have to make first value as default value.

Comment: I have clearly written that I want a Regex, so please read question and then answer.

Comment: didnt see it :).. sorry ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
function selectavalue() {
var selectBox = document.getElementById('selectboxid');
var user_input = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
var str = user_input;

if((str.match(/--Select--/i)) ) 
{
    alert("Please select a value");
} 
else 
{
    alert("The value u selected is"+str);
}
}
```

call this function from your selectbox.onchange="return selectavalue();"